# each(function) de jQuery no funciona como se espera

Tags: jquery

Tengo un pequeño `XML` en una variable para pruebas.

Al buscar una determinada etiqueta de manera directa con `find()` no hay problema, añade su valor al `input text`, pero al buscar con `each`, justo seguido y con la misma búsqueda, no funciona... Debería llenar el segundo `input text`, pero como se puede apreciar, el `alert` correspondiente no aparece.

¿Dónde está el error?

Gracias.

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
                let texto = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n' +
                    '<escrutinio_sitio>\n' +
                    '    <num_a_elegir>350</num_a_elegir>\n' +
                    '    <convocatoria>2019</convocatoria>\n' +
                    '    <ts>1600072004</ts>\n' +
                    '    <votos>\n' +
                    '        <contabilizados>\n' +
                    '            <cantidad>24507715</cantidad>\n' +
                    '            <porcentaje>66.23</porcentaje>\n' +
                    '        </contabilizados>\n' +
                    '    </votos>\n' +
                    '</escrutinio_sitio>';

                $("#escanos-totales").val($(texto).find('num_a_elegir').text());
                if ($(texto).find('escrutinio_sitio')) {
                     alert('Este mensaje se muestra porque el bloque if encuentra la etiqueta "escrutinio_sitio"');
                }

                $(texto).find('escrutinio_sitio').each(function () {
                    alert('Each ha funcionado...');
                    $(this).find('votos').each(function () {
                        $(this).find('contabilizados').each(function () {
                            $("#votos-totales").val($(this).find('cantidad').text());
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="escanos-totales">Escaños totales</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="escanos-totales" min="0" placeholder="" required
                   type="number" value="0">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="votos-totales">Votos totales</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="votos-totales" min="0" placeholder="" required
                   type="number" value="0">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, estás equivocado... si pones `if($(texto).find('yo_no_existo'))` también entra al condicional y muestra la alerta. Esto pasa porque find también retorna una instancia de `jquery`, para saber si encontró o no coincidencias, debes usar la propiedad `.length`. En tu caso el valor es 0 (o sea no encontró nada)

Comment: @Pipe Pero, entonces, la función `each` no tendría sentido. Yo suponía que iteraba una vez por cada coincidencia de las encontradas por su correspondiente `find` ...

Comment: La respuesta de @Masterguru parecía funcionar, pero ha sido borrada...

Comment: Estaba mal, ahora pongo una buena... esa parecia funcionar pero es que intentas recorrer un texto puro como si fuera un objecto XML y no lo es

Comment: efectivamente no tenia sentido y no se ejecutaba porque find no encuentra esa coincidencia. Por lo tanto el each nunca se ejecutaba

Comment: Vale, ahora ya está completa... me olvidé de cambiar la línea anterior que **siempre** entraba en el condicional que ponía: `if ($(texto).find('escrutinio_sitio')) {`. En la respuesta la corrección.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto, donde cambiamos estas líneas:

```
if ($(texto).find('escrutinio_sitio')) {
    alert('Este mensaje se muestra porque el bloque if encuentra la etiqueta "escrutinio_sitio"');
}

$(texto).find('escrutinio_sitio').each(function () {
```

por la que crea un objeto XML correctamente usando el método [parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) de jquery, y que puedes usar correctamente usando `find()` para luego recorrerlo con `each()`, pues tu error era que estabas intentando usar **find()** para buscar en un texto como si fuera un objeto, y luego el **each()** no te funcionaba bien:

```
var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(texto);

if ($(xmlDocument).find('escrutinio_sitio').length > 0) {
  alert('Este mensaje se muestra porque el bloque if encuentra la etiqueta "escrutinio_sitio"');
}

$(xmlDocument).find('escrutinio_sitio').each(function() {
```

### Solución completa

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let texto = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n' +
    '<escrutinio_sitio>\n' +
    '    <num_a_elegir>350</num_a_elegir>\n' +
    '    <convocatoria>2019</convocatoria>\n' +
    '    <ts>1600072004</ts>\n' +
    '    <votos>\n' +
    '        <contabilizados>\n' +
    '            <cantidad>24507715</cantidad>\n' +
    '            <porcentaje>66.23</porcentaje>\n' +
    '        </contabilizados>\n' +
    '    </votos>\n' +
    '</escrutinio_sitio>';

  $("#escanos-totales").val($(texto).find('num_a_elegir').text());
  var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(texto);

  if ($(xmlDocument).find('escrutinio_sitio').length > 0) {
    alert('Este mensaje se muestra porque el bloque if encuentra la etiqueta "escrutinio_sitio"');
  }

  $(xmlDocument).find('escrutinio_sitio').each(function() {
    alert('Each ha funcionado...');
    $(this).find('votos').each(function() {
      $(this).find('contabilizados').each(function() {
        $("#votos-totales").val($(this).find('cantidad').text());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <label for="escanos-totales">Escaños totales</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="escanos-totales" min="0" placeholder="" required type="number" value="0">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="votos-totales">Votos totales</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="votos-totales" min="0" placeholder="" required type="number" value="0">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora sí funciona bien, parece que `$.parseXML(texto)` es la clave de todo. Había probado cosas del estilo, pero nada... Tengo un problema anterior a este código, justo con el `filereader` al que sustituye la variable, voy a ver si lo pongo en otra pregunta...